# Android Gesture dector for deteting a rectangle

Tags: android

Can you please tell me if there is any library/API to detect if user draw a rectangle on screen using gesture?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`android.gesture.Gesture`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture.html) to store a gesture. And [`android.gesture.GestureOverlayView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html) to detect if user draw needed gesture.
Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html)